# Database Cache Memory in Performance Monitor drops down significantly after DBCC CheckDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, dbcc-checkdb, buffer-pool, performance-monitor

We have been monitoring some `SQLServer: Memory Manager`'s metrics, and noticed that after `DBCC CheckDB` job, metric

```
Database Cache Memory (KB)
```

drops down significantly. If to be exact, it dropped from 140 GB cached DB memory to 60 GB. And after that, slowly ramp up again during the week. (Amount of "`Free Memory KB`", went from 20 to 100 GB right after `CheckDB`)

`DBCC CheckDB` is run every Sunday, so Database Cache Memory has to ramp up back again each week

```
What is the behavior of this ? Why CheckDB pushes database pages out of memory ?
```

Second question is why "`buffer cache hit ratio`" did not change after `DBCC CheckDB` completes ?

It was 99.99% on average and after `DBCC CheckDB` job it drops to ~98.00%, and returns back to 99% pretty fast while I expected "`buffer cache hit ratio`" to drop significantly because database data has to be read from storage to RAM again ?

Comment: Regarding BCHR, the reason why it didn't drop further can be because CHECKDB code could be done using read-ahead (RA), and I/O done by RA isn't included when calculating BCHR. Which in turn makes BCHR a pretty useless perf counter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> We have been monitoring some SQLServer: Memory Manager's metrics, and
>   noticed that after DBCC CheckDB job, metric
>
> Database Cache Memory (KB) drops down significantly. If to be exact,
>   it dropped from 140 GB cached DB memory to 60 GB

This is correct, you can clearly see this behaviour when this example `DBCC CHECKDB` command completes at `21h45`

[image]
[image]

---

**Why**

This behaviour is due to the `database snapshot` created by the `DBCC` command being dropped, removing all of its objects in memory.

**You can replicate the behaviour by creating a snapshot of a database, loading some data in memory, and then dropping that snapshot**

```
  CREATE DATABASE MY_DATABASE
     GO
     USE MY_DATABASE 
     GO
     CREATE TABLE dbo.bla(id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                          val int,
                          val2 char(100));



    INSERT INTO dbo.bla(val,val2)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),'bla'
    FROM master..spt_values spt
    CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;
    GO

    CREATE DATABASE MY_DATABASE_SNAPSHOT
     ON  
     (  
     NAME ='MY_DATABASE',  
     FILENAME ='D:\DATA\MY_DATABASE.ss'  
     ) 
     AS SNAPSHOT OF MY_DATABASE;

     GO


    USE MY_DATABASE_SNAPSHOT
    GO
    SELECT * FROM dbo.bla;

     SELECT
      COUNT(file_id) * 8/1024.0 AS BufferSizeInMB
    FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors;
```

**BufferSize before dropping the snapshot**

```
BufferSizeInMB
1061.70312  --before
```

**Dropping the snapshot**

```
USE master
GO
DROP DATABASE MY_DATABASE_SNAPSHOT ;
```

**BufferSize after dropping the snapshot**

```
BufferSizeInMB
824.179687 --after
```

---

> Second question is why "buffer cache hit ratio" did not change after
>   DBCC CheckDB completes ?

This depends on how fast the data is loaded back in your buffer cache.

If your buffer pool fills up over a longer time, it should amount to this ratio staying higher on average.

This corresponds with this part of your question:

> ... It (*Buffer pool datasize*) dropped from 140 GB cached DB memory to
>   60 GB. and after that, slowly ramp up again during the week...

Comment: thank you Randi! when we talk about Internal Database Snapshot made by DBCC CheckDB, is it creating it in memory ? or at disk ? or both